# how to invoke vim with line numbers shown

Tags: vim

I know that from inside `vim` the command to display line numbers is `:set number`.  Is it possible to invoke `vim` so that line numbers are shown from the beginning?

Answer (score 3):

Add 'set number' to your .vimrc file

```
$ echo "set number" >> ~/.vimrc
```

This should then add line numbers by default when you load vim

You can also add other options to the .vimrc file to have things turned on by default

Have a nosey here: http://phuzz.org/vimrc.html. It's an example of a vimrc file.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `set` commands from the vim command line like this:

```
vi +'set nu' yourfile
```

or

```
vi -c 'set nu' yourfile
```

They do the same thing. `+` is present in traditional `vi`; `-c` is POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following line to your file `.vimrc` or `.exrc` (in your `$HOME` directory).

```
set nu
```

This will give you line numbers for whichever file you open.

Comment: I don't have `.vimrc` or `.exrc` in `$HOME` ... should I create them ?

Comment: Yes, you can always create those and set up your preferred environment there.  You can also create keymaps and abbreviations in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin a cat:

```
EXINIT="set nu" vi file
```